# Possible to do silent/unattended install of XFCE/KDE on debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, kde, xfce, vnc

The way I'm installing the DEs:

XFCE:

```
apt install -y xfce4
```

KDE:

```
apt install aptitude tasksel
aptitude install ~t^desktop$ ~t^kde-desktop$
```

Both seem to prompt for a selection for the language/keyboard halfway through. Is there an option to make it auto-select default and proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the noninteractive debconf frontend:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt install -y xfce4
```

This will prevent the packages from asking questions, and the defaults will be chosen.